For the following inner product space $V$ and $T ∈ L(V )$, evaluate$ T ^ ∗$ at a given point in $V$
Pardon for the loose title but I have this question:

For the following inner product space $V$ and $T ∈ L(V )$, evaluate $T^*$ at a given point in $ V$:
$V=P_1(R)$, with $\langle f(x),g(x) \rangle =\int_1^1 f(t)g(t)dt$, $T(f)=f'+3f$, $f(t)=4-2t$

Now what I did was that firstly I took our ordered basis $\beta=(1,x)$ for the $P_1(R)$, (which is orthonormal also). Now I calculated $[T]_\beta$ and found the $$[T^*]_\beta=[T]^*_\beta$$ and then found the $$[T^*(f(t))]_\beta$$ to get the final vector in basis of $\beta$.
But apparently my answer is wrong, and I am also perplexed that I dont find any use of inner product, which might explain why my answer is wrong. I cant seem to understand why my answer is wrong. Thanks in advance.
